# Include more lists of stopwords in logical condition to filter words

Tags: python, list, nlp, nltk

I would need to add further conditions in cleaning data which include removing stopwords, day of week and months.
For day of week and months I created a separated list (I do not know if there is some already built-in package in python to include them). For numbers I would consider isdigit.
So something like this:

```
days=['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday']
# need to put into lower case
months=['January','February','March', 'April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December']
# need to put into lower case

cleaned = [w for w in remove_punc.split() if w.lower() not in stopwords.words('english')]
```

How could I include in the code above? I know that it is about extra if statements to take into account, but I am struggling with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert all your lists to sets and take their union for the final set. Then it's only about checking the membership of your word in the set. Something like the following would work:

```
# existing code
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

days=['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday']
# need to put into lower case
months=['January','February','March', 'April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December']
# need to put into lower case

# add these lines
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
lowercase_days = {item.lower() for item in days}
lowercase_months = {item.lower() for item in months}

exclusion_set = lowercase_days.union(lowercase_months).union(stop_words)

# now do the final check
cleaned = [w for w in remove_punc.split() if w.lower() not in exclusion_set and not w.isdigit()]
```

Comment: Thanks Bitswazsky. About removing all numbers, how could I include this info as well?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Now it should take care of digits as well.